# On electric potential and corresponding formulae

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

Why is it that signed quantities of charge are used in determining electric potential but not electric force (by Coulomb’s law)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed charge *is* used in Coulomb’s Law! Two point charges of the same sign repel. Two point charges of the opposite sign attract.

The proper statement of Coulomb’s Law is in terms of vectors. If $q_1$ is at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $q_2$ is at $\mathbf{r}_2$ then the force $\mathbf{F}_1$ on $q_1$ and the force $\mathbf{F}_2$ on $q_2$ are

$$\mathbf{F}_1 = -\mathbf{F}_2 = k\frac{q_1q_2(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)}{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^3}.$$

Flipping the sign of one of the charges reverses the direction of the force vectors.

If you have only learned Coulomb’s Law in the simplified form

$$F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$

then you may be confused. In this case you have to allow $F$ to be either positive or negative to mean repulsive or attractive (along the line between the charges). You can’t think of this $F$ as the *magnitude* of the force vector.